# DLL missing when I execute .exe inside debug folder. Visual studio 2013 C++ console application

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013

I have a dll missing error when I execute the .exe file inside the Debug folder inside my project folder while debugging my program works perfect. This is the error:

> " The program can't start because Saxon_DBase.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem"

I have the Saxon_DBase.lib file inside my project folder, and added to Linker\Input\ Additional dependencies.
The dll location is fix and is outside my project folder. I have defined the dll path in Debugging\Environment: PATH=I:\DSIM600\Saxon_Run;%PATH%

I wondered if I am missing something.

Thank you very much for your help.

Andres

Comment: The point of debugging a program is to detect the kind of problems your user will have when running your program.  Mission accomplished.  Never mess with PATH, you will fumble your installer or some other program's installer messes up you or you'll invoke DLL Hell.  Very unpleasant support calls.  Use xcopy.exe in a post-build event to copy dependent DLLs into the build directory.

Comment: @Hans Passant you are right, I have been messing up everything. Now I have copied the .exe, .ilk and .pdn where the dll is and works. Thank you very much!